# Avoid Uninitialized Warning - Perl Scope

Tags: perl, scope

This code works without any warnings if I use it without strict or warnings:

```
while (<>) {

        $_ =~ s/^\s+//;
        $_ =~ s/ +\d$/ /g;
        my @fields = split(/\s{2,}/);
        my $atindex = rindex($fields[0],"@",);
        my $username = substr($fields[0],0,$atindex);

        if (length($fields[1]) == 0 || $fields[0] eq 'holder') {
        } elsif (!$fields[2]) {
            print "grant $fields[1] to user '$username';\n";
        } elsif (!$fields[3]) {
            print "grant ", ($fields[2] eq 'any') ? 'execute any' : $fields[2]," on application '$fields[1]' to user '$username';\n";
        } else {
            print "grant ", ($fields[3] eq 'any') ? 'execute any' : $fields[3]," on database '$fields[1]'.'$fields[2]' to user '$username'\n";
        } 
    };
```

However, if I use strict and warnings, I get an error regarding uninitialized values for `$fields[0]` and `fields[1]` at the lines that begin with `my $atindex` and `my $username` and the if statement.

So I tried this code to restrict the use of those values:

```
if (@fields) {
my $atindex = rindex($fields[0],"@",);
my $username = substr($fields[0],0,$atindex);
}
```

But then I get the error at the lines in the if statement that feature `$username`:

```
Global symbol "$username" requires explicit package name at
```

So I tried using a package name instead of the if(@fields) block like so but then I get the original uninitialized warning:

```
package user;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $atindex = rindex($fields[0],"@",);
my $username = substr($fields[0],0,$atindex);
```

So is there a way to suppress that warning besides *not* using warnings?

Comment: Initialize your variables _before_ the `if` statement.

Comment: start by deciding what you do want to happen if `@fields` is empty; then do that and only afterward start worrying about the warnings that alerted you to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution was probably closest to what you want.  But when you say `my $atindex`, it is local to the current block - i.e. the if block you just added.

So you probably want to say:

```
my ($atindex, $username);

if (@fields) {
    $atindex = ...
    $username = ...
}
```

Comment: That sort of worked. The warning about `$field[0]` being uninitialized went away, but I still get the warning for `$field[1]` in the second half of the code where the if statement with the or operator is.

Comment: Yes, I was going to mention that.  You really just need to check the size of your @field array before accessing elements of it.  You can get its size with scalar(@field), or $#field (which returns the maximum index, i.e. size-1).

Comment: So do something like nest that if statement in another one that checks if the array size includes a 1 index value?

Comment: Exactly.  You could also make it the first condition of the if statement, if that looks cleaner.  Since the logical operations are short-circuiting, if fields isn't the right size, the other conditions won't be checked, and you won't get the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd just do:

```
no warnings 'uninitialized';
```

... in the smallest possible scope (i.e. within the `while` loop).